# Redirect sites without certificate to non-ssl instead of serving a default certificate

Tags: debian, ssl, apache-2.4

I am hosting several websites from our customers. Some of them have ssl certificates and thus use port 443 for https and some do not have a certificate.
The sites that have such a certificate are configured to automatically redirect http to https. If I access one of the sites that don't have their own certificate, the one from the vhost file that was loaded first is served, which is in my case my own homepage.

I now want to know if it is possible to have apache redirecting ssl requests to sites that do not have their own certificate to non-ssl so it does not give the "untrusted certificate" warning.

Example:

- domain1.com - SSL enabled (loaded first)
- domain2.com - SSL enabled
- domain3.com - SSL not enabled

When I request https://domain3.com I get the untrusted warning because the certificate of domain1.com is served, which does of course not contain domain3.com as the primary or alternative name.
Instead of that, I want to have a redirect to http://domain3.com

What I already tried was the following configuration, which gives me an SSL error when accessing domain3.com

```
<VirtualHost MyIp:443>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
</VirtualHost>
```

I am not sure if my approach is going in the right direction or if my goal is even achievable. So I am open to all kinds of help. Thanks.

Comment: I would go for "https everywhere", and get certs for all the domains you're hosting. It's quite easy now with [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/).

Comment: This is of course our long-term goal but we wanted a short-term solution until we are done implementing Let's Encrypt in our Hosting infrastructure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not possible without valid certificates.

With https the TLS/SSL negotiation happens first, **before** any content (including redirects) happens. So you need to establish a secure connection (using a certificate) before you can redirect back to http.

If there was any way around this, then that would be a major security hole in https as attackers could just downgrade any request to http.